# jQuery jTable update : data base side won't be updated

Tags: jquery, vb.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-jtable

I'm using the jTable plugin of jQuery in my CRUD application. My problem is, when I click on the update icon, the changed values appear in the jtable , but on the data base side nothing seems to be changed.
I just can't figure out.... what's the source of this  problem ???
here's the script for my view :

```
@ModelType jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.Hik.JTable.Models.Concour

@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Filtering"
End Code


@section CssImport
<style>
    div.filtering {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #EEE
    }
</style>
 end section

<div class="filtering">
<form>
    <label>Numéro: <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" />
          <label> Type: @Html.DropDownList("numero_type", DirectCast(ViewBag.types,    IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)), New With { .id = "numero_type" })
           Nature: @Html.DropDownList("numero_nature", DirectCast(ViewBag.natures, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)), New With { .id = "numero_nature" })</label></label>


    <button type = "submit" id="LoadRecordsButton">Rechercher</button>
  </form>
 </div>

 <div id="Tableau" ></div>
    <script >

   $(document).ready(function () {

    //Initialize jTable
    $('#Tableau').jtable({
        title: 'Liste des concours',


        actions: {

            listAction: '@Url.Action("ConcoursListByFiter")',
            deleteAction: '@Url.Action("DeleteConcours")',
            updateAction: '/DefaultPage/UpdateConcours',
            createAction: '@Url.Action("CreateConcours")'
        },

        fields: {
            numero_concours: {
                title: 'numéro',
                width: '21%',
                key: true,
                create: true,
                edit: false,
                columnResizable: true,
                columnSelectable: true
            },     

            numero_type: {
                title: 'type',
                width: '12%',
                options: '@Url.Action("GetTypeOptions")'
            },
            numero_nature: {
                title: 'nature',
                options: '@Url.Action("GetNatureOptions")',
                width: '21%'
            },

            numero_etape: {
                title: 'Etape',
                options: { '1': 'En cours de programmation', '2': 'soumission', '3':      'validé', '4': 'sorti' },
                width: '21%'
            },
            titre_concours: {
                title: 'titre',
                width: '21%'
            },
            date_de_sortie: {
                title: 'date ',
                width: '21%',
                type: 'date',
                displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                inputClass: 'validate[required,custom[date]]'
            },
            nbre_rangs: {
                title: 'Rang',
                width: '21%'
            },
            nbre_matchs: {
                title: 'Matchs',
                width: '21%'
            }
        }

    });
    //Re-load records when user click 'load records' button.       

    $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#Tableau').jtable('load', {
            numero: $('#numero').val(),
            typeId: $('#numero_type').val(),
            natureId: $('#numero_nature').val()

        });
    });

    //Load all records when page is first shown
    $('#LoadRecordsButton').click();



});
  </script>
```

the script from the controller :

```
 <HttpPost>
    Public Function UpdateConcours(concours As Concour) As JsonResult
        If (Not (ModelState.IsValid)) Then

            Return Json(New With {Key .Result = "ERROR", Key .Message = "Form is not valid! Please correct it and try again."})
        End If
        Try


            _repository.ConcoursRepository.UpdateConcours(concours)
            Return Json(New With {Key .Result = "OK"})

        Catch ex As Exception

            Return Json(New With {Key .Result = "ERROR", Key .Message = ex.Message})
        End Try
    End Function
```

and the script for the UpdateConcours in my MemoryConcours Repositroy :

```
 Public Sub UpdateConcours(concours As Concour) Implements IConcoursRepository.UpdateConcours
        Dim foundConcours As Concour = _dataSource.Concours.FirstOrDefault(Function(s) s.numero_concours = concours.numero_concours)
        If IsNothing(foundConcours) Then

            Return
        End If
        foundConcours.numero_concours = concours.numero_concours
        foundConcours.nbre_matchs = concours.nbre_matchs
        foundConcours.nbre_rangs = concours.nbre_rangs
        foundConcours.numero_etape = concours.numero_etape
        foundConcours.date_de_sortie = concours.date_de_sortie
        foundConcours.numero_type = concours.nbre_rangs
        foundConcours.titre_concours = concours.titre_concours
        foundConcours.numero_nature = concours.numero_nature
        Dim e As Concour = (From o In x.Concours Where o.numero_concours = concours.numero_concours Select o).First()
        x.Entry(e).OriginalValues().SetValues(concours)
        x.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()
        x.SaveChanges()



    End Sub
```

ps: while the updating there's no error message it is just that the values are updated on the table but not on the data base side !!

Comment: Have you debugged the server side to see if the request is making it there? Have you checked the javascript console and network tab in your browser tools to see if there is an error or if the request is being made at all?

Comment: No i didn't and frankly I don't know how I'm a beginner with all this... help !!